# How to convert an Android esri arcGIS Point into latitude and longitude

Tags: android, arcgis

I'm trying to get Latitude and Longitude of a tap over a Android esri arcGIS MapView.

```
        map.setOnSingleTapListener(new OnSingleTapListener() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public void onSingleTap(float x, float y) {
                System.out.println("x:" + x);
                System.out.println("y:" + y);
                // How to get Latitude Longitude coordinates of the point (x,y)?

            }
        });
```

How to get Latitude Longitude coordinates of the point (x,y)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is:

```
Point p=map.toMapPoint(arg0, arg1);
System.out.println("X="+p.getX());
System.out.println("Y="+p.getY());
```

The variable p will have the coordinates mapped in the MapView.

Comment: If i use this code i didn't get exact latitude and longitude value.

Comment: If you want to use WGS84 that gives you latitude and longitude, you need to do a projection of your point. Example: `SpatialReference sp = SpatialReference.create(/*spatial number*/);
  Point aux = (Point) GeometryEngine.project(p,
    map.getSpatialReference(), sp);`. You can search your spatial reference in http://spatialreference.org/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert map point to lat/long you just need to follow this

```
Point mapPoint = mMapView.toMapPoint(point.getX(), point.getY());
//Here point is your MotionEvent point
SpatialReference spacRef = SpatialReference.create(4326);
//4326 is for Geographic coordinate systems (GCSs) 
Point ltLn = (Point)
GeometryEngine.project(mapPoint,mMapView.getSpatialReference(), spacRef ); 
//mMapView is your current mapview object
```

`ltLn.getY()` will give latitude and `ltLn.getX()` will give longitude

Answer (score 1):

I tired this Solution in kotlin and its working as expected

```
       val sp = SpatialReference.create(4326)
       // where Location is the Point
       val locationPoint = GeometryEngine.project(location, sp) as Point
       val lat = locationPoint.x
       val lng = locationPoint.y
```

Comment: Latitude is `locationPoint.y` and longitude is `locationPoint.x`, otherwise this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
map.setOnSingleTapListener(new OnSingleTapListener() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public void onSingleTap(float x, float y) {
                System.out.println("x:" + x);
                System.out.println("y:" + y);


Point p=map.toMapPoint(x,y );

 SpatialReference sp = SpatialReference.create(/*spatial number*/);
 Point aux = (Point) GeometryEngine.project(p, map.getSpatialReference(), sp);

System.out.println("latitude="+aux.getX());
System.out.println("longitude="+aux.getY());

            }
        });
```

for spatial number spatialreference.org